# select disperse scatters from points distributed in a plane

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have `N=200 points` (x and y coordinates known) distributed in a plane.

I want to select `M=10` of them, and then there will be `M*(M-1)/2 = 10 * 9 / 2 = 45` edges within them.

I need to keep these `10` points disperse enough, which means that I want to select those `10` points in such a way that would give the maximum of the minimum edges' length.

In other words, I would like to solve an optimization problem (finding *maximum*) of the function

`F = min (lengths_of_all_45_edges)` by varying the chosen `10` points.

Any fast algorithm to implement it?

Comment: Not completely clear what you've mean by "large enough": the distance should be higher that some threshold value, or it should be maximized? If latter, what to be maximized - distance between all of the selected points or smth else? Please give us more details.

Comment: Also, is “some” a fixed number of points? If not, what criteria are you envisioning?

Comment: It is better, but not yet clear. Did you mean min ( sum_for_each_selected_point( sum_of_distances_to_other_selected_points ) )? Result is still greatly depends on the number of chosen points. I'm talking about boundary conditions on this number. If the number could be any, that the obvious solution will be to choose only 2 points and select just those that have maximum distance?

Comment: @PavelK I mean min(distance between each pair within chosen points), and what about just choose fixed 10 points?

Comment: I've modified it to make it clearer

Comment: I've added a formal definition of the optimization problem to be solved, so this question is not unclear anymore (as it has strict definition of what to be found). Please, reopen it

Comment: Section 4.1 of this paper gives a simple greedy algorithm that does very well on the problem.  Basically pick an arbitrary subset of M points, find the point that contributes to the max min edge length, and try to change it to the best unused point.  Iterate that until convergence.  http://graphics.uni-konstanz.de/publikationen/2011/farthestpoints/Schloemer.etal-2011-FPOPSwMMD.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can get the minimum spanning tree and then look for any 10 edges that makes the shortest path.